# Android Studio CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/dpmd": "/system/lib64/libdpmframework.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Tags: android-studio

**I Have Build my app in my android studio But, when I'm building the apk myself on my device, I get the following errors**
**This is my code in build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidattendancesystem"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
```

**And I am Getting this error "A/linker: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/dpmd": "/system/lib64/libdpmframework.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit"**

Answer (score 0):

Hi add this code in your Build.gradle. i was having the same issue

in dependencies block

```
 
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

in android block add the following

```
   buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

now check if the following version is also updated if not then change update as given below, if already exist then replace with this line

```
   buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
   minSdkVersion 23
   targetSdkVersion 30
```

Hope it was helpful